# Adding content of NSArray to Swift Array

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am using both swift and objective-c in my app.

I have a CustomClass and I want to create a swift array for the class and add content to it from my objective-c class called oldClass that has an array of these objects in a NSArray called arrayOfCustomClass.

```
var newArray = [CustomClass]()
newArray += oldClass.arrayOfCustomClass
```

This causes an error:

```
'[(CustomClass)]' is not identical to 'CGFloat'
```

Any help?
thanks
Reza

Comment: Show the rest of the actual code! What is `oldClass`? What is `arrayOfCustomClass`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Swift knows nothing of what's in an NSArray. You must cast the NSArray explicitly to a `[CustomClass]` (and you'd better not be lying or you'll crash at runtime).

Comment: But there may be additional issues here, which won't be known until you reveal what `arrayOfCustomClass` really is.

Comment: As my answer below shows I needed to cast to AnyObject before I could cast to the CustomClass

Comment: This can be done safely with an optional cast - see my answer.

Comment: @reza23 You still haven't shown your Objective-C code as I requested so you are getting a false need to cast to AnyObject. There's something here you need to fix, but you are refusing to show what it is.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to work is:

```
newArray += oldClass.arrayOfCustomClass as AnyObject as [CustomClass]
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this safely you just need to try an optional cast. If you think the `NSArray` only has elements of type `CustomClass`, you can do this:

```
var newArray = [CustomClass]()
if let customArray = oldClass.arrayOfCustomClass as? [CustomClass] {
    newArray += customArray
}
```

If you want to extract the `CustomClass` elements (a little different from what you asked, I know), this is the way:

```
var newArray = [CustomClass]()
for element: AnyObject in oldClass.arrayOfCustomClass {
    if let custom = element as? CustomClass {
        newArray.append(custom)
    }
}
```